# Wrapper for a container of resources

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, c++11

I often find myself working locally with a containers of raw pointers or other resources, where the resources are allocated dynamically. To make sure the resources are not leaked in case of an exception or some other return condition, I use a simple wrapper for the container that has a destructor that frees the resources. In an attempt to generalize this into a useful utility, I came up with this struct (please ignore the issues with template template argument, it's not the point here):

```
template<typename Resource, 
        template <typename ELEM, 
        typename ALLOC=std::allocator<ELEM>> 
        class Container=std::vector>
struct ResourceContainer {
    Container<Resource*> resources;
    ~ResourceContainer() {
        std::for_each(resources.begin(), resources.end(), [](Resource* resource) { 
            delete resource; // more generally, use a template functor to free the resource
        });
    }
};
```

Sample usage:

```
class Bar;
void foo() {
    ResourceContainer<Bar> bars;
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        bars.resources.push_back(new Bar());
    }
}
```

The problem is that as a general utility, I have to start worrying about the scope of this struct, and preventing users from copying it, returning it, etc... In general, I would like it to behave like boost::scoped_ptr. Does anyone know of an existing solution for this? A simple modification that I can make to prevent usability bugs?

I cannot use a vector of smart pointers because I have legacy code I don't own that expects a container of raw pointers.

Comment: I don't see the problem with using a vector of smart pointers in the first place.

Comment: I forgot to add that using smart pointers is not an option due to legacy interfaces and also they are too heavy-duty for this

Comment: Do you need thread safety? If not you can make your wrapper Singleton / purely Static. You can also pass a loader functor if you want emplace construction.

Comment: It's likely that several threads would need such a wrapper, each one locally (not shared), so singleton/static is not good

Comment: I have no idea what "too heavy-duty" means (does it mean "zero-overhead"?), and I have no idea why you can't provide the right interface while keeping smart pointers underneath.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes, shared_ptr is heavy duty because it involves reference counting, which is not needed for the local scope. Legacy code (beyond my control) often accepts containers of raw pointers, so I'd have to convert the smart pointers into such every time I use it.

Comment: So... don't use `shared_ptr`? I have no idea who mentioned `shared_ptr`. Did you know about `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Anyway, have you looked at boost::noncopyable? It sounds like it gives you what you want.

Comment: Can you specify inheritance for your pointers? This would allow you to inherit from a base template pointer which would be added in your wrapper and store a pointer to the wrapper, allowing deletion both from the pointer (explicit) and from the wrapper (automatic).

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes, thanks! boost::noncopyable serves to avoid some misuse.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the [Boost Pointer Container Library](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/) is exactly what you need.  From the Motivation section:

> Whenever a programmer wants to have a container of pointers to heap-allocated objects, there is usually only one exception-safe way: to make a container of smart pointers like boost::shared_ptr This approach is suboptimal if
>
> 1. the stored objects are not shared, but owned exclusively, or
> 2. the overhead implied by smart pointers is inappropriate
>
> This library therefore provides standard-like containers that are for storing heap-allocated or cloned objects (or in case of a map, the mapped object must be a heap-allocated or cloned object). For each of the standard containers there is a pointer container equivalent that takes ownership of the objects in an exception safe manner.

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of thing I was looking for. Sadly, I see a way of exposing the actual container (say, std::vector) to the legacy code, but I see it working for many other cases.

Comment: @killogre: Do you mean you *don't* see a way of exposing the actual container?  And does the legacy code expect a `vector<T>` (instead of, say, providing function templates that take iterator ranges)?

Comment: yes I meant that I don't see it, and yes, the legacy code doesn't take iterators :(

Comment: Hmmm.  I briefly thought you might be able to craft a special `allocator` that deletes its pointed-to elements, but that would work its way into the vector's type, meaning that won't work either :(